# Problem with Illegal Characters in SQL Server Assembly

Tags: c#, database, t-sql, stored-procedures, assemblies

I am working with Directory.GetFiles in C#.  This code is turned into an assembly which is then used in a T-SQL script.  Here is the code line that I believe is the problem:

**C# Code:**

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(path, ext, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

**Error (T-SQL script):**

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'G:\Photography\Archive\SPBKF3~L'.

I'm assuming the tilde isn't a legal character to use for a folder name in Windows because the only folders that cause this error are the ones with a tilde.  The files are being shared between Mac and Windows systems and I've found that file and folder names have been a problem in the past.

I'm having a difficult time understanding why the Directory.GetFiles method would even find a directory that doesn't exist.  The folder displays in Windows Explorer but I cannot access the folder.

Is there something I can do to avoid these problem folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`~` is not an invalid character - I just tried creating a directory with the name `SPBKF3~L`, and I also wrote up a quick C# app to run your sample code on that directory and it worked fine.

There must be something else happening here - are you **absolutely sure** that the directory exists? (try copying and pasting the path into an explorer window)

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding, Kragen.  I navigated to the parent directory in Windows Explorer and it displayed as if it existed.  When I try to access the folder, though, Windows tells me it isn't there.  This problem occurs if I copy & paste the path or if I just open by double-clicking the folder.

Answer (score 3):

SPBKF3~L looks suspiciously like an 8.3 shortened filename. Are you sure this isn't happening somewhere?

Comment: Do you know of a way that this might actually display in Windows Explorer?  I've only ever seen this happen in a command prompt.

Comment: It could be a directory artifact left over from a mac creating or deleting a directory here. One thing you can try is to turn off 8.3 support on the parent folder using fsutil.

Answer (score 2):

Check the permissions on `G:\Photography\Archive\SPBKF3~L` and ensure that the user account the SQL Server instance is running under can see the folder.